# Login button need to be clicked twice in order to login

Tags: java, android, android-studio, authentication

I am making an attendance app on android studio, but whenever I try to log in using correct credentials I need to click twice on the login button to move forward to the next activity. I tried Asynctasks because of its background thread, after the same result I just reverted back

So, at first click nothing happens but as soon as please wait dialog box disappears and if I click like in under a second or two then it moves to the next activity.

clicking on login fetches some data from the server after the server has validated that the login exists and is correct. when data is received then the new activity is supposed to start since that received data will be shown in the next activity. (i have a list that is checked if it has data then it moves forward)

Login Activity code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //sign up and login button
    private Button btnSignUp;
    private Button btnLogin;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private RequestQueue Queue;

    //data URL
    private String extractStudentDataURL = "https://asuiot12.000webhostapp.com/checkLoginCredentials.php";
    private String extractEnrolmentsDataURL = "https://asuiot12.000webhostapp.com/retrieveEnrolledCoursesData.php";

    //editText
    private EditText editTextEmail, editTextPassword;
    private ConstraintLayout login;

    //string variables
    public static String inputEmail;
    private String inputPassword;

    //array list to store enrolled courses data
    public static LinkedList<Courses> enrolledCoursesData = new LinkedList();

    //static variable
    public static StudentData studentData;

    //shared preferences to maintain the login status of the user...
    public static SharedPreferences sp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        login = findViewById(R.id.login_activity);
        login.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.button_sign_up);
        btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.button_login);

        // sp = getSharedPreferences("login", MODE_PRIVATE);

        editTextEmail = findViewById(R.id.editText_RA_emailAddress);
        editTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.editText_RA_password);

        //login button listener
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                inputEmail = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
                inputPassword = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

                if (inputEmail.isEmpty()) {
                    editTextEmail.setError("Email Required");
                    editTextEmail.requestFocus();
                } else if (inputPassword.isEmpty()) {
                    editTextPassword.setError("Password Required");
                    editTextPassword.requestFocus();
                } else {
                            enrolledCoursesData.clear();
                            ExtractData();
                  }
            }
        });
        //signUp button listener
        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegistrationActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });
    }

    //retrieving data from the server and checking the login credentials
    private void ExtractData() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, extractStudentDataURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject data = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        int success = data.getInt("success");
                        if (success == 1) {
                            Long CNIC = data.getLong("CNIC");
                            String name = data.getString("Full_Name");
                            String fss = data.getString("FSS");
                            String regNo = data.getString("Reg_No");
                            String batch = data.getString("Batch");
                            String department = data.getString("Department");
                            int semester = data.getInt("Semester");
                            Long mobileNo = data.getLong("Mobile_No");
                            String nationality = data.getString("Nationality");
                            String MACAddress = data.getString("MAC_Address");
                            String homeAddress = data.getString("Home_Address");
                            String email = data.getString("Email");
                            String loginPassword = data.getString("Login_Password");
                            String photo = data.getString("Photo");

                            studentData = new StudentData(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(CNIC)), new BigInteger(String.valueOf(mobileNo))
                                    , semester, name, fss, regNo, batch, department, nationality,
                                    MACAddress, homeAddress, email, loginPassword, photo);

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Plz wait....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            // to get data of courses in which student is enrolled
                            extractDataOfEnrolments(email);

                            if (!enrolledCoursesData.isEmpty()) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CoursesActivity.class);
                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putSerializable("list", enrolledCoursesData);
                                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }

                        } else if (success == 0) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Incorrect username or password",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {


                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            public Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email", editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim());
                params.put("password", editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim());
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    //retrieving data of enrolments from server
    private void extractDataOfEnrolments(final String email) {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, extractEnrolmentsDataURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject data = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        String courseCode = data.getString("Course_Code");
                        String courseName = data.getString("Course_Name");

                        Courses courses = new Courses(courseCode, courseName);
                        enrolledCoursesData.add(courses);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            public Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email", email);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

If layout code or server-side PHP code is required to better understand the question, then please do ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding as to how threading works.

In your `ExtractData` method and its `onResponse` handler, you call `extractDataOfEnrolments()`, which is itself asynchronous:

```
// to get data of courses in which student is enrolled
extractDataOfEnrolments(email);

// the list hasn't been filled yet, will be empty!!!
if (!enrolledCoursesData.isEmpty()) {
}
```

You then immediately inspect the `enrolledCoursesData` list and start the `CoursesActivity` if not empty.  The `extractDataOfEnrolments()` has an asynchronous callback (`onResponse()`) that hasn't completed yet, so the list would be empty.

You might consider moving the `startActivity` code into `extractDataOfEnrolments()`, e.g.:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
try {
  JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject data = array.getJSONObject(i);
     String courseCode = data.getString("Course_Code");
     String courseName = data.getString("Course_Name");
     Courses courses = new Courses(courseCode, courseName);
     enrolledCoursesData.add(courses);
  }

  // now your list is populated, so now Ok to startActivity
  if (!enrolledCoursesData.isEmpty()) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CoursesActivity.class);
     Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
     bundle.putSerializable("list", enrolledCoursesData);
     intent.putExtras(bundle);
     startActivity(intent);
  }

} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Comment: so like threads running at same time, the enrollment thread starts and it isnt finished and during that the extract data doesn't wait and moves to check the list for data. is it like this. it worked but i dont quite get it.

Comment: asynchronous programming is complex, but you need to get it or you'll create very buggy apps ;-)    Logging statements that include `Thread.currentThread()` might help understand your code flow better.  For example, you'll see that the `ExtractData()` function returns before the `onResponse()` callback is called.